# Disable a css rule in the style chain

Tags: css

I have a small problem and I'm not sure there is a real way to do what I want easily.

I have multiple stylesheets available:

- a Bootstrap stylesheet is loaded first
- Multiple modules are loaded

In one module, there is a rule like this:

```
.container .container {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

This effectively prevent me from using stacked containers in my layout. I'd like to disable this rule.

I can technically override it before or after it is declared but I don't want to reset the styles... Let say I just want this rule to cease to "work".

I tried to override it with:

```
    .container .container {
        padding-left: inherit !important;
        padding-right: inherit !important;                
        width: inherit !important;
    }
```

But that doesn't work. What I'd like to achieve is effectively disable a style in the stylesheet chain since the bootstrap has multiple styles with media queries, it could be a bit complicated to reapply the bootstrap styles for the container after the css stylesheet that breaks my styles is loaded.

As far as I know there is no way to do that other than reapplying the styles.

Comment: Consider using the `unset` property value.

Comment: @torazaburo as far as I know, it will disable all the previous styles and not a particular one.